# PrestasShop 1.6 Set custom order status

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I created in CMS custom order status like "Send to approval" and I want to set this status in my order created in mypaymentmodule. I can see ID in CMS but how to get this ID in module?

```
$mypaymentmodule->validateOrder($id_cart, [ID OF STATUS] , $total, $mypaymentmodule->displayName);
$order = new Order(intval($mypaymentmodule->currentOrder));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you created status manually from backoffice, it stored only in `order_state` table, to get all statuses in module you can use:

```
$order_states = OrderState::getOrderStates($this->context->language->id);
foreach ($order_states as $state) {
    if($state['name'] == 'Send to approval')
        $status_id = $state['id_order_state'];
}
echo $status_id;
```

but do it like this not good idea, be better create order state programmatically and store it e.g. in Configuration and then use just `Configuration::get('CUSTOM_STATE_NAME')`